# Term for the different uses of "are": one which applies an adjective independently, and one which denotes a relationship

Tags: be

There are definitely at least two ways in which the word "are" is used. Consider the following:

> Book A and Book B are red.

vs

> Book A and Book B are similar.

In the first use, it is applying an adjective independently to multiple objects. You can view it as syntactic sugar for

> Book A is red and Book B is red.

However, the second sentence doesn't allow such an expansion.

Now, I come from a CS and math background, so my view of this is a bit theoretical (to me, it seems that there is a difference in composition between the two example sentences). Grammatically or linguistically, is there such a concept as the difference I have described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [1] *Book A and Book B are red*.
>
> [2] *Book A and Book B are similar*.

Yes, there is a difference.

Example [1] is called **distributive** coordination, while [2] is called **joint** coordination.

In [1] the property of being red applies to book A and book B separately -- it is distributed between them; whereas in [2] the property of being similar applies to the two books jointly, as a group.

Answer (score 0):

Both "are" and "is" are tenses of "be", and "be" can mean several things.  The definitions of "be" (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be)) we are concerned with is:

> D: to have a specified qualification or characterization

Your first and third examples are:

> Book A and Book B are red.
>
> Book A is red and Book B is red.

This is the English language equivalent of the distributive property.  If Book A and book B are red, then I can distribute the verb and adjective to both while conveying the same meaning.  Instead of a compound subject, I now create a compound sentence.  This is exactly what you describe in your question.

Your second example is:

> Book A and Book B are similar.

"Similar" describes a relational characteristic.  You cannot distribute "similar" to apply to each noun individually (without additional context) because it requires two objects to form a comparison.

To explain in CS terms, think of it as "are" being a token that relies on the following token to define its own behavior.

Certain following words may define characteristics of each of the preceding nouns:

> These books are expensive.

Others may define characteristics between each of the preceding nouns (

> These two are lovers.

Lack of a following word may describe its inclusion in a previous statement

> Which books are on sale?
>
> These books are.

Comment: Is there a term that describes this difference? "Similar" is a ___ word, in the sense that it has this effect on the token "are".

Comment: Comparative is the best descriptor I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your question is assuming the answer has anything to do with the properties of the verb *to be*.

Rather, it's your choice of adjective that is not allowing you to use the transitive property on these sentences.

Your first example uses a simple descriptive adjective. *Red*  It requires no comparison to work. Hence, the logic:

> A *is* C. B *is* C. A & B *are* C.

Your second example is a different type of adjective. It's a comparative adjective.  The logic still applies.

> A is similar. B is similar. A & B are similar.

But, because you used a comparison you're left asking *similar to what?* if you view it as two singles.

You'd have similar issues with any comparison. Taller, greasier, stinkier, uglier, etc.